# Switch GPU based on power source

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, gpu

Is there a way to use a high performance GPU when my MBP is connected to AC power and use automatic switching when it's on battery? I have latest OSX and Mid 2012 MacBook Pro if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recall if [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io/) allows you to adjust the usage of the card on different power systems or not but worth investigating.

Comment: [Power source based switching was removed](http://gfx.io/switching.html#power-source-based-switching)

Comment: Yep, gfxCardStatus can't do it.